# Why does this query not complete in a reasonable amount of time?

Tags: mysql, regex

The following query including subquery on MySQL 8.0.15 will not complete after 15 minutes.

This query is trying to find six-digit values in the "del" table that are not in the IMA table. The "Message" field in the REGEX_SUBSTR has other text values so this just extracts the six-digit portion subject to the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    ID 
FROM
    del
WHERE
    ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        REGEXP_SUBSTR ( Message, '\\d{6}' ) AS ID1 
    FROM
        IMA 
    WHERE
        AND Message LIKE '%deleted%'
    )
```

Each of the queries individually complete in less than 20 seconds, but together there's a huge problem.

Table sizes are less than 30,000 records for each of the two results.

I tried creating an index on the Message field.

The computer has 128 GB RAM and an i9 processor.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try with subquery preprocessing, in a temp table for example?

Comment: There is a "AND" in excess after "where" keyword in your subquery, don't think it will change anything anyway ... as above suggested, try with cte

Comment: Please be more precise than `six-digit values in the "del" table` -- Do you mean some particular column is equal to such?  A particular column has those 6 digits as a substring?  What happens with a 7-digit substring in `IMA`?  In `del`?  Provide some sample data for both tables and point out what the "output" should be.

Comment: Thanks to all! Separating out the data into two tables and doing the sub-query that way was the best solution. I appreciate all the terrific input and ideas.